# validates_presence_of attribute that is not present on form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Inside my `User.rb` model I validate presence of `username` and `name`

```
 validates_presence_of :username, :name
```

However, only the `username` field is present on the form while `name` is created using a `before_validation` callback like this.

```
  def set_username_as_name_if_empty
    if self.username && self.username.present?
      self.name = self.username if self.name && self.name.empty?
    end
  end
```

This work as long as the `name` field is present on the form (as input or hidden doesn't matter).

My question is how can I achieve the same without having to add the `name` field on the form? Sounds like a bit unnecessary to add it as a hidden value just because is required.

Any idea?

Comment: if you do this in before validation, no need to add the field in your form, it should work

Comment: https://gist.github.com/4205936

Comment: Great, that actually works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to simplify your validation method:

```
def set_username_as_name_if_empty
  if name.blank?
    name = username if username.present?
  end
end
```

Because doing the following doesn't raise any error:

```
1.9.3p0 :038 > nil.present?
 => false
```

I don't understand exactly your question but if you meant

> "Am I forced to have an input (even hidden) in my form to avoid a
>   validation failed?"

I would say no, you don't need this input because you set the `name` attribute before the validations.

Comment: funny, we were anoyed byt the same thing,+1

Comment: Ahah yea, I hate these long parts of code just for basic validation/testing too!

Comment: Actually, the only code that worked for me is the first version of @apneadiving gist: https://gist.github.com/4205936/19d8dae41b219d988d7d494b39e01d925875dd1a